# Need to sum distinct rows, not distinct values

Tags: php, mysql

```
+------+------------+----------+--------+
|  id  |  course    |   std_id |  marks |
+------+------------+----------+--------+
|  1   |     1      |    1     |   9    |
|  2   |     2      |    2     |   5    |
|  3   |     1      |    3     |   5    |
|  4   |     1      |    1     |   6    |
|  5   |     2      |    1     |   4    |
+------+------------+----------+--------+


+----------------+----------------+
| course         |  credit        |
+----------------+----------------+
|    1           |     5          |
|    2           |     5          |
+----------------+----------------+
```

I need to get sum of students marks and credits of distinct course order by desc

Like:

```
+---------+------------+-------+
|std_id   |  sum(marks)|  sum()|
+---------+------------+-------+
|  1      |     10     |    10 |
|  2      |     5      |    5  |
|  3      |     5      |    5  |
+---------+------------+-------+
```

Comment: What have you tried? Its not like we are query makers for fun. I mean, it would be nice to know what you tried, instead of asking us how to make the query, and say: do this. Besides of that .. it feels like I am making someones homework now. Correct me if I am wrong ;)

Comment: How are you determining the `sum()` for `std_id = 1`, I don't see how you are getting a `sum(marks)` = 10?

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused by your question combined with your title. This answer should well help you with the question you pose in the title - but some of the output that you post is puzzling:

```
select
    c.std_id,
    sum(c.marks) as marks,
    sum(c.credit) as credits
from
    (
        select distinct
            a.id,
            a.course,
            a.std_id,
            a.marks,
            b.credit
        from
            marks a
                join courseCredits
                    on a.course=b.course
    ) c
group by
    c.std_id,
    c.course,
order by
    std_id desc
```